# Validate an array of values, output an error and stop script if one value fails?

Tags: php, arrays, validation, email, loops

I have an array of emails. I would like to do some validation on each one to see if it is more or less the proper format. This script is validating emails for the administration side of a website. This particular piece of the administration side is for sending newsletters to particular groups, each containing an array of emails.

I am adding the functionality to add a group with administrator specified recipients. This would become useful if the administrator was getting rid of a particular group of newsletter recipients and wanted to add them to another group before destroying the original group.

I have come up with a way to throw an error if any of the items in the array do not match the validation, however, it seems like there should be a better way to do this in PHP. I have not been able to find an alternative method.

```
   $email_array_data["count"] = count($email_array);
foreach($email_array as $email) { 
  if (email_validation_function($email) {
    $email_array_data["passed_validation"]++;
  } else {
    $email_array_data["failed_validation"][] = $email;
  }
}
if ($email_array_data["count"] == $email_array_data["passed_validation"]) {
  Send The Emails
} else {
  Echo The Emails That Failed Validation
}
```

This script works pretty well, but it seems like there would be a better way to do this that checking that every email met the requirements, then comparing the number of emails that passed/failed validation and the count of the emails array.

Is there a better method?

Comment: few different approaches, but nothing 'better'

Answer (score 1):

First, you should check out `filter_var()`. It's a great function for validating tons of data, especially emails (see [here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.filter-var.php)).

There are many ways to handle errors. Based on what I can see from your script, you are only considering the array valid if all emails are valid. You could throw an exception.

```
$is_valid = filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL);

if( ! $email )
    throw new Exception('Invalid email address supplied');
```

If you go this approach, you could catch the exception using a `try {} catch {}` Just another approach I guess.

Comment: I was unaware of the inbuilt function. I'll be sure to use it.